# How did the scientists know that the UFOs would be landing at the Devil's Tower that night?

Tags: close-encounters-of-the-third-kind

After they decipher the co-ordinates, it seemed like they were expecting them to land there that very night. Is it because the UFOs had been visiting every night or did I miss something?

Comment: Who said they knew? They were just prepared for when they came.

Comment: Maybe the aliens saw people showing up to Devil's Tower and said "finally, now we can go and land."

Comment: I thought things were happening kinda asap

Comment: this means something

Answer (score 1):

> How did the scientists know that the UFOs would be landing at the Devil's Tower that night?

**TL;DR**: They didn't know (or didn't know they knew). They had the location, not the day/time. So they just decided to go there and hope/wait for something to happen. I don't think you missed anything. We must keep in mind that this is a sci-fi movie, so many things aren't told or explained<sup>1</sup>, some need to be mysteriously happening so that the magic works and the plot leaves some questions open. Beside that, these visitors have been watching and studying Humans for a looong time, and they have a much more advanced technology. They may have decided to show up as soon as they see that Humans have decypher their message.

It's not explained anywhere in the script versions I searched or in any other available data on the internet. But it seems *very* logical to do that. If you think these numbers are coordinates, and if it's the only thing you have, what can you do but go there and expect for something to show up?

If you're a scientist, or a detective, and the only clue you have is an address, you just go there and check the place, and search it all over. In this case, waiting seems to be their best option.

> Scientists broadcast the phrase to outer space, but are mystified by the response. This is a seemingly meaningless series of numbers (104 44 30 40 36 10) repeated until Laughlin, with his background in cartography, recognizes it as a set of geographical coordinates, which point to Devils Tower near Moorcroft, Wyoming. [Close Encounters of the 3rd Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_Encounters_of_the_Third_Kind)

FUN fact: W 104 44 30 - N 40 36 10 aren't in Wyoming but in [Colorado](https://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/l/W+104+44+30+N+40+36+10/2440521/).
The [Devil's Tower](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devils_Tower) coordinates are W 104 42 55 - N 44 35 26.

**About the part where people knew (or not) where to go or when to go**, there's an [interview](https://www.bfi.org.uk/sight-and-sound/interviews/close-encounter-with-steven-spielberg) of Steven Spielberg about the subject, and it may look like an inception:

> **Are there many reported instances of the third kind?**
>
> > There have been hundreds. Betty and Barney Hill, the interracial couple from New Hampshire, had that experience when they were taken aboard a space craft. They were allegedly both given thorough physical examinations, Betty communicated with some of the entities in the vehicle, and then they forgot the entire episode completely. They spent two years having a horrendous time with each other and their marriage, persistent nightmares. Then they went to a psychiatrist, and separately they were put under hypnosis and were able to piece together what happened during those three missing hours, when they suddenly noticed they were ninety miles further down the road. There’s a book on it by John C. Fuller called The Interrupted Journey; it was also the basis of a television movie.
> >
> > The contact was that Betty was shown a star map with a configuration of broken lines and solid lines, and different points which she didn’t attempt to memorise but which she looked at very carefully. ‘They’ explained to her that the broken lines were trade routes and the solid lines were expeditionary routes, and under hypnosis she reproduced the map. When it was published in this book in the mid-60s, no one could figure out what the hell the map meant. And then three or four years later, four crucial stars were discovered by our most advanced telescopes, and those stars completed Betty’s map. They were able to find the exact duplicate of her map existing up there.

In another [interview](https://www.rogerebert.com/interviews/top-secret-steven-spielberg-on-the-brink-of-the-close-encounters-premiere), Steven Spielberg said:

> And do the beings communicate with humans?
>
> > “In several cases, communication has been reported.”
>
> Do they talk in the observer's native language?
>
> > “**People have reported that communication seemed to be generally in the form of a telepathic exchange**. When questioned, they say that the beings made sounds that were not understood, but that somehow they knew what they meant anyway. That the meaning was present inside their minds. Once again, don't ascribe this to me; I'm reporting the observations of others.”

<sup>1. "When a news program about a supposed train wreck near Devils Tower airs on television, Roy and Jillian recognize the same mountain they have been visualizing. They, along with other travelers experiencing similar visions, set out for Devils Tower in spite of the public warnings about toxic gas." (from [Wikipedia page about the movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_Encounters_of_the_Third_Kind)). **Why and How they saw this moutain isn't explained, just said.**</sup>

Comment: I always assumed there were tons of people like Roy and Jillian in the world who were somehow drawn to Devil’s Tower and that some of them were either government employees, members of the armed forces, and/or interviewed by the government.

Comment: @ToddWilcox : thought so too, there's no hard evidence, but logic applies in such a sci-fi movie I believe :)

Comment: @ToddWilcox: digging deeper with that idea in mind, I've found some more data from 'the man' himslef talking about his movie, and expanded on my answer. Seems like you were right.

Comment: “this is a sci-fi movie, so many things aren't told or explained” — I don't think that follows. Many science fiction movies are very well thought-out and explain everything they need to. Yes, this particular one doesn't (which is probably why I don't like it much), but that's down to the filmmakers, not the genre.